# Passing id through the check_box value in Ruby on Rails using form_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two controller `project_controller.rb` and `service_controller.rb` . I have a field in `Project` named as `service_id`.

When I create project, the value of `service_id` is kept as null by default. So now I need to update the `service_id` field of `Project` with the `id` of `Service`.

For That I have created a form using the `project` object. shown below :

```
<%= form_for(@project) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <% @services.each do |service| %>
      <%= f.label "#{service.name}" %>     # Here I want to pass the array of
      <%= f.check_box :service_id %>       # service_id through value of check box
    <% end %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Now in source it is coming like this..

[image]

Please help .. Thanks

Comment: Your project has a single service that needs to be selected from a list of services?  If so then you should be using either a select drop-down or a radio set.  Check boxes will allow the user to select multiple services so which would you store on the project?

Comment: Yes exactly I need multiple services.. that's why I have chooses check box

Comment: @GraemeMcLean.. Sorry my mistake.. I am changing my question little bit. I want to store array of `service_id`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you refer to [Rails API](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder.html#method-i-check_box) you see

```
check_box(method, options = {}, checked_value = "1", unchecked_value = "0")
```

so, to pass custom value to check box, you need

```
<%= f.check_box :service_id, {}, service.id, '' %>
```

Comment: @MikDiet.. This error is coming - `undefined local variable or method `service_id' for #<#<Class:0x9a1ac08>:0xa99eef4>`

Comment: of course, instead you should put actual `service_id` you want to add to model.

Comment: I update answer with `service.id` instead `service_id`, hope this helps