# Pass checked box list to controller in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have table which shows list of parameters and I need to check (Check box) few parameters and find Ids of those selected parameters in data base.How to pass selected check boxes values to controller and find id of each selected parameters in rails?

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: it will be better if you can show some code here, so other users can give more explanations

Comment: @Alex Roz one suggestion to think about. Google railscast checkbox

Comment: [This SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23709455/passing-id-through-the-check-box-value-in-ruby-on-rails-using-form-for) might help you.